# Javascript accessing a class within a table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single page application where a number of fields contain a weight. If the weight is in pounds I want to show it in aquamarine, if in kilograms in yellow. The color to be used is in `sUnitColor`. All fields containing a weight have a `class='weight'`. I change colors with:

```
$('.weight').css('color',sColorUnit);
```

This works fine throughout the page except within table td cells even though they have `class='weight'`. They remain unchanged.

Is there something special about table cells that precludes this working?

I've also tried:

```
$('td .weight').css('color',sColorUnit);
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any and all suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not add space between `td` and `.weight` as the space is making your selector a [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). The selector `td.weight` means all *tds* having class `weight`.

```
$('td.weight').css('color',sColorUnit);
```

Comment: @Amadan explain comment more. it is confusing

Comment: @guradio: No need, it served its purpose :) (but if curious, look up [s///](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html), then note Adil's edit).

Answer (score 0):

> If class is in the same element do not use any space between element
>   and class, if a space is there, it means element have a class with
>   that name.

Try with this:

```
$('element.classname').css({color:sColorUnit});
```